# Getting the depth of properties in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, parcel, depth

Is there a way to get the depth of a parcel in ArcGIS Basic (or QGIS)? Depth meaning the distance from the road (frontage) to the rear of the property. I should also mention that not all parcels are rectangular or square, many parcels are irregular shapes.

Comment: Can you include a few diagrams and/or links describing how depth of properties is defined for some of those with irregular shapes, please?

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish your task, your workflow could go something like this:

1. Ensure you polygons have some sort of unique_id on them
2. Convert your polygon vertices to points (maintaining the unique_id on each point)
3. Run a near analysis for the points to the roads
4. Run a statistics on the results of the near to find the maximum distance from a road for each unique_id - this should give you depth

Comment: That could work, I am just trying to visualize how that would work for irregular parcels. For example, if a property was wedged in between two roads, I would not be able to derive depth at the longest point. In this case, both roads would be taken into account, when in reality the property is only accessible by one road.